# Why can't I get output from Parallel.ForEach in the code below?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

```
public static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> urls = new List<string> {
            "https://www.microsoft.com",
            "https://www.google.com",
            "https://www.amazon.com"
        };

        List<string> Results = new List<string>();
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " 1");

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " 2");
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var p = Parallel.ForEach<string>(urls, (url) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " 3");
                Console.WriteLine(url);
                var content = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
                Results.Add(url + " " + content.Length);
                Console.WriteLine(url + " " + content.Length);
            });
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Main program");
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get an output like the one below.

```
1 1
Main Program
```

Why is there no output from the places I marked as 2 or 3?

So there is no output from `Console.WriteLine` in `Task.Run()` and `Parallel.ForEach()`.

I want to print all thread ids.

Comment: Because the program immediately exits before the other threads get a chance to run. Put a `Console.ReadLine();` at the end to stop that from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Task.Run` method returns a `Task` object, that represents the completion of the asynchronous operation. You have to wait for the operation to complete, otherwise the main thread will terminate, and shortly after the process will terminate too after aborting all background threads. The simplest way to wait the task to complete is by calling the [`Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait) method:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    //...
}).Wait();
```

Answer (score 1):

Signature of `Main` function can be updated to return `async Task` instead of `void` and use `await` on `Task.Run()` as shown below. In the updated code, the `Parallel.ForEach` was updated as well to use the new `Parallel.ForEachAsync()` to utilize `async/await` magic

```
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> urls = new List<string> {
        "https://www.microsoft.com",
        "https://www.google.com",
        "https://www.amazon.com"
    };

    List<string> Results = new List<string>();
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " 1");

    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " 2");
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        await Parallel.ForEachAsync<string>(urls, async (url, token) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " 3");
            Console.WriteLine(url);
            var content = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            Results.Add(url + " " + content.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(url + " " + content.Length);
        });
    });

    Console.WriteLine("Main program");
}
```

Recommendation would be to remove `Task.Run` altogether unless it is required for some other reason in code

```
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> urls = new List<string> {
        "https://www.microsoft.com",
        "https://www.google.com",
        "https://www.amazon.com"
    };

    List<string> Results = new List<string>();
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " 1");
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync<string>(urls, async (url, token) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " 2");
        Console.WriteLine(url);
        var content = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        Results.Add(url + " " + content.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(url + " " + content.Length);
    });

    Console.WriteLine("Main program");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Task.Run` you say to thread that it could do other thing when the task is idle. So your `Task` will not be waited by the `Main Thread`. Like in the code bellow:

```
Task.Run(() => { /*task-job*/});
```

In order to wait the Task be completed to resume your code flow, just put *`await`* keyword to synchronize the Task with Thread when its job is done. The `Thread` will wait till every `Task`checked with *await* be finished in the queue to die.

```
await Task.Run(() => { /*task-job*/});
```

Also, you have to update your Main method signature, to allow async calls:

```
static async Task Main()
```